# Unable to create a google meet link in Django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I am getting credentials from the service account.

```
  SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(path , scopes=SCOPES)
```

To generate the meet link here's my body code

```
event = {
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-12-29T11:00:00",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-12-29T10:00:00",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
  },
    "conferenceData": {"createRequest": {"requestId": "sample123", "conferenceSolutionKey": {"type": "hangoutsMeet"}}},

}


    event_response = service.events().insert(calendarId=calendarId, body=event,conferenceDataVersion=1).execute()
```

I am getting the error:-

```
returned "Invalid conference type value.". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Invalid conference type value.'}]">
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be some concern with authentication and permission. You can check and ensure that Google calendar API was enabled on the project. Double-check that the scopes ([`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar) and [`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events`](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events)) are sufficient in creating events.

Comment: I did all these, nothing worked